# How do I add submenu dropdown to my current wp theme top menu?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a new WP Theme and in the header have inserted a top menu / nav ... but it's just 1 level depth.

How do I modify this so that I have show subpages in a dropdown style please?

Here is the current code:

```
<div class="header_right">

<ul>

<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>

<li><a href="#" id="signin"></a></li>

</ul> 

</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `depth=0` to get the entire list of pages including sub-pages nested in heirarchical `li` elements.  Also, you will have to write corresponding CSS code for the sub-menu pages to appear in drop-down style.

You can take any theme having the same menu style as reference.  [Twenty Eleven](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/twentyeleven/) theme has a very simple menu with this functionality and easy to understand CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

For your header use: wp_nav_menu();

To get dropdown sub menus that dropdown when hovered over you'll want to add some code to the previous line:
[paste-bin adding sub-menu](http://pastebin.com/iYwuC39b)

There's some very helpful advice and useful CSS at [Capability Wordpress Help Blog](http://kav.in/wordpress-dropdown-menu-wp-nav-menu-css/)